# A trig problem involving 2 unknowns

Tags: trigonometry

I'm stuck on a problem that goes like this:

A system of equations are given

$$\cos x + \cos y = 1.2$$

$$\sin x + \sin y = 1.4$$

Solve the system for $0 < x < \pi$ and $0 < y < \pi$

How am I supposed to tackle the problem? Any help would be highly appreciated =)

PS. (I found $y$ in terms of $x$, but from there I dont know what I'm supposed to do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:$(\cos x+\cos y)^2 = 1.44, (\sin x+\sin y)^2 = 1.96 \to 2+2\cos(x-y) = 3.4$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1=(1.4-\sin y)^2+(1.2-\cos y)^2\\=3.4-2.8\sin y-2.4\cos y+1$$
then solve for $y$